# What is the difference between lib/src and /bin in dart?

Tags: file, dart, package, conventions, dart-pub

I know that lib/ is where we put all our library files and /bin is where we put our entrypoint for our command-line app. I know both of them are public lib/ and bin but i'm unable to understand the convention of using lib/src which according to the official docs should contain: **implementation code**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`lib/` is the directory that contains shareable code.
It can be shared

- to other top-level directories like `bin/`, `web/`, `example/`, `test/`, `tool/`, ... in the same package
- to other packages that have this package as a dependency.

`lib/src` by convention contains the private implementation of the public API exposed by `lib/` or `lib/xxx` where `xxx` is not `src`.

`bin` is reserved for command line apps and contains the Dart entry point scripts to execute them (the files that contain `main() {...}`).

In `pubspec.yaml` you can define executables https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec#executables that allows you to run scripts from `bin/` by just executing `foo` to have `dart somePath/bin/foo.dart` executed (using `pub global activate my_package_with_foo`).

Answer (score 9):

See [Pub Package Layout Conventions - Implementation files](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout#implementation-files)

> The libraries inside `lib` are publicly visible: other packages are free to import them. But much of a package’s code is internal implementation libraries that should only be imported and used by the package itself. Those go inside a subdirectory of `lib` called `src`. You can create subdirectories in there if it helps you organize things.
>
> You are free to import libraries that live in `lib/src` from within other Dart code in the same package (like other libraries in `lib`, scripts in `bin`, and tests) but you should never import from another package’s `lib/src` directory. Those files are not part of the package’s public API, and they might change in ways that could break your code.
>
> When you use libraries from within your own package, even code in `src`, you can (and should) still use `package:` to import them.